# Sum of entries made one

Tags: calculus

Assume that I have performed some loop and summed values of $x_i$ and the sum is as follows $$S= \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i *0.0001) = 0.9999$$

However I would like to have the sum to be equal to 1 i.e, 
$$\sum_{i} (x_i *0.0001)= 1$$

How much should I add to each of the entires $x_i$ so that I end with sum of values equal to one.

Is the solution the increment to each $x$

$$increment = \frac{\frac{0.9999}{0.0001} - \frac{1}{0.0001}}{n}$$

Thanks

Comment: If you multiply each term of a sum by a constant,  the effect is to multiply the result of the sum by that constant ie. the constant can be "taken outside" the summation.

Comment: yup this is what I have done I think.

Comment: I think you have your subtraction backwards,  but otherwise OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two simple canonical choices (and there are certainly others). Either divide each $x_i$ by their current sum $s$, or let $\delta = 1 - s$ where $s$ is the current sum and then add $\delta/n$ to each term if you have $n$ terms in your sum. Of course there are other "less canonical" ways, e.g. you could just add $\delta$ to just one of the terms (whatever term you want).

Answer (score 0):

$$I_1=\sum _{i=1}^n{x_i}*0.0001=0.9999$$
$$I_2=\sum _{i=1}^n{(x_i+ \delta)}*0.0001=1.0000$$
$$I_2-I_1=\sum _{i=1}^n{(\delta)}*0.0001=0.0001$$
$$ n*\delta=1$$
$$\delta = { 1 \over n}$$

Comment: Please see the one below.

Comment: Not sure how can people change comments after edit original.

Answer (score 0):

$increment=\displaystyle{\frac{1-0.9999}{\left(n*0.0001\right)}}=\frac{1}{n}$

Answer (score 0):

$$I_1=\sum _{i=1}^n{x_i}*u=X_1$$
$$I_2=\sum _{i=1}^n{(x_i+ \delta)}*u=X_2$$
$$I_2-I_1=\sum _{i=1}^n{(\delta)}*u=X_2-X_1=\Delta$$
$$ n*\delta={\Delta \over u}$$
$$\delta = { \Delta \over (nu)}$$
For $\Delta=0.0001$ and $u=0.0001$
$$\delta = { 1 \over n}$$